# Filter out a certain IP adreess

Tags: regex

Looking for the right regex to filter out a various IP adress:

Lets say I have a logfile like this:

```
Sep 14 12:37:03 100.100.100.145:64439 -> 180.180.150.2:25 (TCP) SMTP
Sep 14 15:36:01 100.100.100.145:64439 -> 180.180.180.2:25 (TCP) SMTP
Sep 14 12:37:03 100.100.100.145:64439 -> 180.180.180.2:25 (TCP) SMTP
Sep 14 15:36:01 100.100.100.145:64439 -> 180.180.180.2:25 (TCP) SMTP
Sep 14 12:37:03 100.100.100.145:64439 -> 180.180.180.2:25 (TCP) SMTP
Sep 14 15:36:01 100.100.100.145:64439 -> 180.180.180.2:25 (TCP) SMTP
```

I`m able to search for:

```
\b180\.180\.180\.2\:25\b.*SMTP
```

But I want to find everything what is not my right SMTP Server, so I look for a "negative word boundary".

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: are you using `grep`? If you want to find everything that doesn't match, use `grep -v <pattern>`

Comment: I´m not using grep, is not applicable .

Comment: What is your programming language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, if ***lookarounds*** are supported:

```
(?!.*\b(?:180\.180\.1[58]0\.2)\b)^.+$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/tS5gH2/2).

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$6 ~ /^180\.180\.1[58]0\./ && $6 !~ /\.180\.2:25$/ && $8 == "SMTP"'
```

will print lines which match the first regex and not the second.

Your question doesn't reveal whether this is exactly what you want, but it should hopefully get you started.